# VS Code hover option working only in a new file. Doesn't work on an existing file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, hover

VS Code hover option is working only in a new file.
When I open an existing file, the hover option doesn't work. I put the cursor on the functions, modules.., no info displayed. Also, the modules aren't colored like usual.
Thanks

The hover option is activated

Comment: and same for IntelliSense

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have to ensure that `Python` and `Pylance` extesions have been installed. Then you  could use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to check whether you have chosen the correct python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, the modules aren't colored like usual.

It seems to be that the [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview) for the file you're opening isn't set to Python. In most cases, VS Code can automatically set the language mode through identifying a language's syntax or the file's extension.

You haven't really given much information about your problem to work with, but start off by checking the file's extension (should be .py), and make sure that the language mode is set to Python (it should say "Python" in the [status bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/getstarted/userinterface/hero.png).

It would be very beneficial to provide some more information about your problem, such as the code that's causing the problem or any extensions you're using, as there're several factors that could cause an issue like this (e.g., you're using a module which doesn't provide any documentation to present upon hovering over, or maybe the function you're using belongs to a third-party library, which might require some configuration to set up diagnostics for).